# Convert binary string to decimal number

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, homework, number-systems

I'm finishing the book *C Primer Plus* by Stephen Prata and I wrote as a part of the homework program to convert binary string to decimal number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned int uint;

int strbin_to_dec(const char *);

int main(void) {
    char * wbin = "01001001";
    printf("%s to dziesietnie %d.\n", wbin, strbin_to_dec(wbin));
    return 0;
}

int strbin_to_dec(const char * str) {
    uint result = 0;
    for (int i = strlen(str) - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        byte k = str[i] - '0'; // we assume ASCII coding
        k <<= j;
        result += k;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Questions:

- How's the efficiency of this program?
- Are byte operations faster than
  normal?

Comment: You can compile your code with certain flags. It goes like this `gcc app.c --ansi --pedantic -Wall`

Comment: `str[i] - '0';` does not need "assume ASCII coding".  That is valid for all encodings.

Answer (score 7):

Well, first of all the description is wrong.
`strbin_to_dec()` should be `strbin_to_i()`, because it parses a base-2-number, instead of converting it to base-10.

Next, refrain from using your own defines as much as possible, if there is an appropriate type already.

Third, assuming correct input is generally naive. Assuming corrupted or malicious input is far wiser.
Your code breaks if any character is neither `0` nor `1`, or if the number is too big for an `unsigned`.

Finally, it's more straight-forward to parse from beginning to end, only needs a single pass, and is probably due to both reasons slightly more efficient, if you really care. Still, what input you get might be important to the determination.

Regarding your question whether byte-operations are faster than wider operations, probably only on 8bit-microcontrollers or the like.
Still, micro-optimisations are hard to do correctly, and have hardly any significant effect, especially if you don't know what to optimise for: Source clarity (should be the default), source size, compiled code size, code throughput, memory bandwidth, ...
Let's hope you chose the right optimisation-options, or the point is moot anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Answering only your specific question here: "Efficiency" is really the wrong thing to be worrying about. For example, look at what your code generates when given to clang 5.0.0:

https://godbolt.org/g/esUA7q

It looks like a bunch of gobbledigook, but what it means is that clang very heavily vectorized the code. This makes the code extremely fast for long chains, but not as fast as it could be when handling 1 or 2 digits.

Performance is ALWAYS contextual and relative, and unless you know what context you are operating under, you can't really know wether it's efficient or not.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you tracking position in `j` and scaling `k` to suit? All you have to do is iterate left-to-right, looking at each character. On each loop iteration, just shift `result` 1 bit left and add the value of the current bit.

If you can assume that you'll always have valid input — a string of ASCII `0` and `1` characters, I'd write it something like this:

```
int strbin2i(const char* s) {
  register unsigned char *p = s;
  register unsigned int   r = 0;

  while (p && *p ) {
    r <<= 1;
    r += (unsigned int)((*p++) & 0x01);
  }

  return (int)r;
}
```

If you want to be a good citizen and validate input, you might do something like this:

```
int strbin2i(const char* s) {
  unsigned char *p = s ;
  unsigned int   r = 0 ;
  unsigned char  c     ;

  while (p && *p ) {
    c = *p++;

    if      ( c == '0' ) { r = (r<<1)     ; } // shift 1 bit left and add 0
    else if ( c == '1' ) { r = (r<<1) + 1 ; } // shift 1 bit left and add 1
    else                 { break          ; } // bail on oinvalid character

  }

  return (int)r;
}
```

Comment: Few things bother me about this code: 1) repeatedly checking for `p` in the `while` condition when it can be done once at the very beginning. Compiler should be able to optimise it but then...see later. 2) Use of `register` nowadays is probably completely useless (unless you use it to stop yourself to write `&p`). Any modern compiler is perfectly able to determine there isn't aliasing here (unless you're compiling with `-O0` but they why bother?) 3) `'0'` is 91 then `*p & 0x01` returns `'0'` and `0` for `'1'`.

Comment: 4) In C bitwise `&` is perfectly defined for signed integers (at least for two's complement). You MIGHT be writing code where signed integers have another representation (one's complement, for example) where a negative 0 is a trap but then...you're failing when casting to `int` to return a value. Either don't bother or do it well. `<<` is UB for negative operands. 5) This is just my very personal opinion but I can't stand code formatted to look like columns like your 2nd example...it's a pain to write, read and maintain (with a very opinionated visual appearance...)

Comment: 6) When being a good citizen you may check for the number of bits in your input

Comment: Um... no. Don't know what encoding you're talking about, but in Unicode and ASCII both, the code point 91 dec/`0x5b` hex is `[`, left square bracket, while the code point `0x91` hex/145 dec is Unicode's "PRIVATE USE 1" control character. The code point for Unicode/ASCII `0` is `0x30` hex/48 dec, while `1` is at `0x31`, decimal 49. If you know your string contains only ASCII `0` or `1`, all you care about it is the low-order bit, which masking the char off via `c & 0x01` gives you.

Comment: You're right, I wrongly used 91h as decimal. Please ignore point 3!

Comment: `(*p++) & 0x01`  assumes `'0'` has an even value and `'1'` is odd.  Certainly that is very common.  OTOH, `r += *p++ - '0';` is clear and does not share that limitation.

Comment: Casting away `const`-ness is usually frowned upon.  Consider `const unsigned char *p = s;`

Comment: Yes, that is true. The code is dependent on `0` being even and `1` being odd, but that's is true statement for all of Unicode, ASCII, EBCDIC, Windows-1252 and ISO 8859-1. I'm not aware of any character encodings that map decimal digits otherwise. Your code, `*p - '0'` likewise makes the assumption that decimal digits occupy (1) contiguous positions in the encoding, and (2) that `0` precedes `1`. Those assumptions are true for the encodings mentioned above, but not necessarily true for _all_ encodings — but I can't imagine any encoding in current use for which both assumptions aren't true.